# Angular 5 Route with children and named outlets not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-router, router-outlet

**Updated to clarify my problem**

I'm trying to get routes with children and named outlets work but with no luck.
The origin idea is to build a tabbed navigation, to have deep links inside my app. 
I've break down my sample stackblitz project to the real problem for better understanding.
<s>It seems like it is navigating to the route ´/(list:first/(detail:second))´ but the `DetailComponent` will not load.</s>
I need a primary route with multiple child routes and named outlets ('list', detail', ...) to represent a url chain build up: /overview/(list:first) (first tab), /overview/(list:first/(detail:second)) (second tab), and so on.

The `[routerLink]` on the a tag looks like this: 
`<a [routerLink]="[ { outlets: { detail: ['second'] } }]">Component 1</a>`

After some more research it seems like the route `/overview/list/(detail:detail/1)` is found:
`NavigationEnd {id: 2, url: "/overview/(list:first/(detail:second))", urlAfterRedirects: "/overview/(list:first/(detail:second))"}` ...

My overview.component.html looks like this:

```
<h2>Overview</h2>
<router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="detail"></router-outlet>
```

It is working when the named outlet 'detail' is inside my list.component.html.

```
<p>
   <a [routerLink]="[ { outlets: { detail: ['second'] } }]">Component 1</a>
</p>
<router-outlet name="detail"></router-outlet>
```

But this is not what I want.

So I think I don't have a route config problem, but a problem with nested components. Is this case not intended? Do you have any other ideas to solve this problem?

This is my Router-Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {ListComponent} from '../overview/list/list.component';
import {DetailComponent} from '../overview/detail/detail.component';
import {OverviewComponent} from '../overview/overview.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'overview',
    component: OverviewComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'first', component: ListComponent, outlet: 'list', children: [
          { path: 'second', component: DetailComponent, outlet: 'detail'
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true}) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class RouteModule { }
```

Please see my stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgattb

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tobias, It's clear you're having a route configuration issue, but it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: I've edited the question for clarification

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a solution to this?